# How to resolve the error "[ErrorException] file_get_contents(/var/www/laravel/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-14.04, file-get-contents, laravel-5

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04** on my machine. I installed composer and then **laravel** in the document root i.e. **/var/www**

I also gave **-R 777** persmission to folder **laravel** present in directory **/var/www**

Then I go to directory **laravel** using **cd /var/www/laravel** and run the following command **php artisan** and I got to see all the available commands there.

Then I typed in **php artisan key:generate** and got the error

```
[ErrorException]  file_get_contents(/var/www/laravel/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

[image]
Here I got stuck actually, can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: Check whether there is a .env file in your project root. Normally there would be a .env.example file which you need to change to .env file with your own settings

Comment: check whether .env exist in /var/www/laravel. It may be hidden. If not exist, rename .env.example to .env.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Rename `.env.example` to `.env` in your laravel root folder

Comment: for me exist both file and i removed `.env.example` and updated `.env` but getting same error.

Answer (score 6):

The `.env` file is not yet present because you will first need to create and configure it.

Do the following

```
# Navigate to the correct folder
$ cd /var/www/laravel

# Copy the example file to make a .env file
$ cp .env.example .env

# Set the parameters
$ vi .env
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create it & rerun the command.

```
# cd /var/www/laravel 
# cp .env.example .env       //renames .env.example to .env
# php artisan key:generate 
Application key set successfully.
```

Answer (score 4):

Rename .env.example to .env and fill all properties.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration

Answer (score 3):

Probably you missed your `.env` file in laravel project folder.So make `.env.example` to `.env` file. Also give the required database connection.

`.env`file look like this: (Fill up with required database connection)

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Hope this will help you.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If, like me, you *did* have a `.env` file, you may find it has permissions that are too tight to allow your current user to write to it (and by implication the php artisan command your current user is attempting to run). I had changed all my Laravel files to be owned by `www-data:www-data` and made my current user a member of the `www-data` group, and was thus a little stumped by this error.

However, I soon realised that my `.env` file has the following permissions:

`-rw-r--r--`

...meaning the user which owns the file gets read-write, but the group and world can only read. Since my current user is a member of the *group* `www-data`, it can only read, not write.

(You can check your file permissions by doing `$ ls -la`)

If you have the same situation, you have two choices; loosen the file permissions on that file (with `chmod`) or use `sudo` to run your php artisan commands. I chose the latter, since this is a production server for me and I like the tight permissions.

Comment: Allowing a web server to own (i.e. write to) your code and configuration files is not "tight permissions" at all. Files should be owned by another user and `www-data` only given read permissions, except for the `storage` directory. It doesn't even need read access to .env in a production environment, since configs should be cached with `artisan config:cache` before serving.

Answer (score 0):

Might be someone is looking for the answer
so here is the answer by which I solved the issue
Normally copying the .env.example file and then renaming it ,does not work
so here is the suggestion
Dont do in that way
Just do
`cp .env.example .env` in the command lin

and then change the db name Or Password etc

Answer (score 0):

### Never change The permission to 777

Make a Copy of the `.env.example` file:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Make sure it has the same user and group as the other files:

```
ls -al
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user     778 Dec  7 13:29 .env
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user    778 Dec  7 13:25 .env.example
```

If it is a different user and group change it using:

```
sudo chown -R user:usergroup .env
```

Now it should work.